# What's the difference between "click" and "onclick" when creating an element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the difference between

```
$("<a>", {
    "id" : "myId",
    "text" : "my link",
    "href" : "#",
    "onclick" : function() { return false; }
);
```

and

```
$("<a>", {
    "id" : "myId",
    "text" : "my link",
    "href" : "#",
    "click" : function() { return false; }
);
```

?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using `onclick` creates an *attribute*, and its value should be a string that refers to a function, not an actual function.  Using `click` creates a *property* on the element, and its value should be the function itself.

So, the first one is written incorrectly; should be like this:

```
$("<a>", {
    "id" : "myId",
    "text" : "my link",
    "href" : "#",
    "onclick" : "somefunction()"
} );
```

where "somefunction" is defined in the global scope:

```
window.somefunction = function() { return false; }
```

Comment: It should be `"onclick" : "somefunction()"`, if you want the function to be called.

Comment: @dbaseman good answer. Though it can still be improved by explaining the difference between an attribute and a property in this context and why it would still work if you assign a function to onclick attribute instead of a string.