# Why click() method does not trigger behaviour while actual clicking does?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to programmatically click the "listen" button on a Google Translate page (https://translate.google.com/#en/es/javascript)

For some reason this code does not produce a sound:

```
document.getElementById('gt-src-listen').click()
```

while actual clicking on the button does.

Why these two are not identical and how can I programmatically emulate a click in this case?

Comment: See this: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906486/how-can-i-programmatically-invoke-an-onclick-event-from-a-anchor-tag-while-kee). Seems like it is addressing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using vanilla javascript I think the event you are trying to use is `onclick`, You can see the difference between the both of them in this SO answer [What's the difference between "click" and "onclick" when creating an element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852899/whats-the-difference-between-click-and-onclick-when-creating-an-element-wit)