# Is it possible to add onclick events to input fields generated by jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, onclick

This is the code I'm trying to get working.

```
            var inputText = $('<input>', {
                type: 'text',
                name: id,
                onclick: function() {
                    $('#' + nextQuestion).show();
                }
            });
```

However, when I inspect the DOM and the resulting jQuery object, the onclick method is null. Do I have the syntax wrong?

[image: Your permanent name DOM object]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on these two answers [What's the difference between "click" and "onclick" when creating an element with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852899/whats-the-difference-between-click-and-onclick-when-creating-an-element-wit), [.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

> An attribute value may only be a string whereas a property can be of
>   any type.

Therefore, `onclick` creats an attribute and value should be string that refers to a function.

```
var inputText = $('<input>', {
       type: 'text',
       name: id,
       onclick: "somefunction()"
 });

somefunction() {}
```

`click`creates a property on the element and value should be an actual function.

```
 var inputText = $('<input>', {
   type: 'text',
   name: id,
   click: function () { 
      $('#' + nextQuestion).show();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick reply! This code stumped me last night on this project that I just want to get done already. I'm only on the JavaScript and haven't even gotten to the PHP/MySQL yet :'(

Answer (score 0):

may be this way ?

```js
var inputText = $('<input>', { type: 'text', name: 'something' });

inputText.onclick = function() { console.log('hello') }

console.log( inputText.onclick )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This was my second try and it didn't work after drawing the HTML.

Comment: @PatPeter and what about jQuery $( document ).ready(function() {... ?

Comment: so everything is ok?